# pandas agg using "intermediate" column without recomputing [group size] times the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

Let's say I have a DataFrame `df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan,3,4,5,3], 'b':[11,22,22,11,22,22,22]})`

```
     a   b
0  1.0  11
1  2.0  22
2  NaN  22
3  3.0  11
4  4.0  22
5  5.0  22
6  3.0  22
```

I want compute a reduced dataframe where I group by `b`, and where my column depends on the groupwise mean. Specifically, I want the column to contain the

**number of elements in `a` that are smaller than the group wise mean**.

For this I found a solution which seems like it could be improved because I am guessing it recomputed the mean 2 times for the '11' group and 5 times for the '22' group:

**Slow solution** using groupby, agg and NamedAgg:

`df.groupby('b').agg(c=pd.NamedAgg(column='a', aggfunc=lambda x: sum(i<x.mean() for i in x)))`

```
dff=df.groupby('b').agg(c=pd.NamedAgg(column='a', aggfunc=lambda x: sum(i<x.mean() for i in x)))

print(dff)

    c
b    
11  1
22  2
```

Do you know a better way where the mean is only computed once per group?

I have searched parameters in pandas merge, concat, join, agg, apply etc. But I think there must be a savant combination of these that would achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use python's `sum`, use the vectorial counterpart, it will enable you to compute the mean only once per group:

```
df.groupby('b')['a'].agg(c=lambda s: s.lt(s.mean()).sum())
```

output:

```
    c
b    
11  1
22  2
```

##### Speed comparison

```
## provided example

# vectorial approach
1.07 ms ± 33.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# loop
2.86 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


## 70k rows

# vectorial approach
3.19 ms ± 391 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# loop
7.67 s ± 104 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks, would the speed be the same if you put the lambda function into a named function `fun` outside and did `agg(c=fun)` ?

Comment: @hildes11946 the change would be negligible

Comment: Maybe last question if you don't mind. What if the function was not something like mean() or mode() or quantile() but something more complex? Is there still a way to avoid recomputing it many times?

Comment: If you can't vectorize, then yes write a named function and compute it once in the beginning. I'd need to see a real example to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, if having a large dataset (millions or more of obs), then using `merge` turn out to be more efficient and faster than using `lambda` or `transform`.

```
tem = df.groupby('b')['a'].mean().reset_index(name='mean')
df = pd.merge(df, tem, on='b', how='left')
df.loc[df['a']<df['mean']].groupby('b')['a'].count().reset_index(name='c')
```